# Django UpdateView with multiple models and multiple forms don't work

Tags: python, django, post

I am working with two different forms that loads info from two different models. One form is disabled to edit and the second form is enabled.
Everything is right until I use UpdateView, when I try to make changes on the enable to edit form nothing happens. I am new in Django and found the code on a tutorial and adapted it to my project.

Why UpdateView is not saving changes?

models.py:

```
class Sitioproyecto(models.Model):
    .
    .
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre_del_sitio

class Sitiocontratado(models.Model):
    sitioproyecto = models.ForeignKey(Sitioproyecto, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    .
    .
    def __str__(self):
        return self.sitioproyecto.nombre_del_sitio
```

forms.py:

```
class SitioContratadoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Sitiocontratado
        exclude = ['slug',]
        widgets = {
        'fecha_de_contratacion' : forms.DateInput(attrs={
          'type' : 'date',
          'class' : "form-control pull-right",
          'id' : "fechadecon",
           }),
        'sitioproyecto' : forms.Select(attrs={
          'type' : 'text',
          'class' : "form-control",
          'id' : 'nombresitio',
          }),
          .
          .
        }
```

views.py:

```
class CrearSitiosContratadosView(CreateView):
    model = Sitiocontratado
    template_name = 'sitios/contratados/editar_contratado.html'
    form_class = SitioContratadoForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pagina:tabla_contratados')

class UpdateSitiosContratadosView(UpdateView):
    model = Sitiocontratado
    second_model = Sitioproyecto
    template_name = 'sitios/contratados/editar_contratado.html'
    form_class = SitioContratadoForm
    second_form_class = SitioProyectoForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pagina:tabla_contratados')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UpdateSitiosContratadosView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk', 0)
        sitiocontratado = self.model.objects.get(id=pk)
        sitioproyecto = self.second_model.objects.get(id=sitiocontratado.sitioproyecto_id)
        if 'form' not in context:
            context['form'] = self.form_class()
        if 'form2' not in context:
            context['form2'] = self.second_form_class(instance=sitioproyecto)
        context['id'] = pk
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object
        id_sitiocontratado = kwargs['pk']
        sitiocontratado = self.model.objects.get(id=id_sitiocontratado)
        sitioproyecto = self.second_model.objects.get(id=sitiocontratado.sitioproyecto_id)
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=sitiocontratado)
        form2 = self.second_form_class(request.POST, instance=sitioproyecto)
        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form2.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, form2=form2))
```

template:

```
{% block content %}
<form class="form-vertical" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="box box-primary">
  <div class="box-header with-border">
    <h3 class="box-title">Agregar Sitio</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="box-body">
  <div class="row justify-content-start">
  <fieldset class="col-md-3 form-group" disabled>
    <label for="fechadeval" class="control-label">Fecha de Validación</label>
    {{ form2.fecha_de_validacion }}  
  </fieldset>
  <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
    <label for="fechadecon" class="control-label">Fecha de Contratación</label>
    {{ form.fecha_de_contratacion }}  
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-start">
  <fieldset class="col-md-8 form-group" disabled>
    <label for="fechadecon" class="control-label">Nombre del Sitio</label>
    {{ form.sitioproyecto }}  
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="col-md-2 form-group" disabled>
    <label for="estatus" class="control-label">ID del Sitio</label>
    {{ form2.id_sitio }}  
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="col-md-1 form-group" disabled>
    <label for="estatus" class="control-label">Candidato</label>
    {{ form2.candidato }}  
  </fieldset>
  .
  .
</div>
<div class="box-footer">
  <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'pagina:tabla_contratados' %}">Regresar</a>
  <button type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you also made a SitioProyectoForm. Did you check if the POST is sending the correct information?

Answer (score 0):

In get_context() and post() replace-

```
context['form2'] = self.second_form_class(instance=sitioproyecto)
```

with

```
context['form2'] = self.second_form_class(instance=request.Sitiocontratado.sitioproyecto)
```

and simply save it!! that's it

you don't need to deal with pk